# How to set url as webapi in the .net core web?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In Web Application I created a Page:DetailPage

```
public void OnGet(int id)
{
    var bll = new BLL.Articles();
    Item = bll.GetModel(id);
    if (Item == null)
    {
        RedirectToPage("Blogs");
    }
}
```

The URL is

```
localhost/Detail?id=1
```

Can I make it as the web API URL such as `

```
localhost/Detail/1
```

I added `[HttpGet("id")]` but is not working as expected.

Comment: Check this out in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-a-page-route

Comment: @Nkosi thank you I add it options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Contact", "TheContactPage/{text?}.html"); is right?

Comment: @Nkosi I can not find the Model.RouteDataTextTemplateValue page does not cotain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add this to the top of your `*.cshtml` pages:

```
@page "{id:int}"
```

Then in your details pages:

```
public void OnGet([FromRoute] int id)
```

No need to modify your `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: Thank you @crgolden but only int is ok the {id:string} is not work

Comment: `string` is default, so you can just use `@page` in that case (without the binding)

Comment: Well, in this case it is working fine but I personally think by declaring all razor options in a single place its more elegant and you have full control over routing as well `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Detail", "alias/{id}");`

Comment: @Masoud Keshavarz When you modify your `Startup.cs`, you tightly couple your pages to a specific app implementation. This makes it difficult to separate them into a reusable Razor Class Library, if desired. With many pages, your `Startup.cs` will also have a lot of hard-coded strings.

Comment: @crgolden If only @ page then [FromRoute]is also needed?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) provided the proper [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-a-page-route) in comments you must modify `Startup.cs`

Change `ConfigureServices` method like this:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_0)
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Detail", "Detail/{id}");
});
```

Now implement your standard view

```
@page
@model Item

<p>@Model.[property]</p>
```

Comment: what [property] mean? same in the cs file?

Comment: @daotian properties you have declared before in `Item` object. Like `Id`, `Name`, `ModifiedDate`... . `Item` is what you are using in this line: `Item = bll.GetModel(id);`